# Foreach loop doesn't work

Tags: php, loops, foreach

can anyone please please tell me what is wrong with this code? The loop at the end of the first if statement only returns one result instead of all of them. I've attached the output as well. Thanks very much in advance.

[image]

```
    <?php



if ( $instagramid ) {
 echo "


<br><br>
<span style=\"float:left; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
font-size: 14px;
float: left;
line-height: 32px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top:12px;
padding: 0px 3px 0px 5px;
\">
<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://instagram.com/".$username."\"><img width=\"80\" border=\"1px\" src=\"".$profilepic."\"></a></span>
<br>
<div style=\"margin-left: 50px;\">
     <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 0.00%;
   width: 75.00%;
   background-color: #f4f4f4\">
       <span style=\"
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; \"><a style=\"color: #3f729b; font-weight: bold; \" target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://instagram.com/".$username."\">".$username."</a> @ instagram</span>
    </div>
    <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 0.00%;
   width: 82.00%;\">
        <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 0.50%;
   width: 33.00%;\">
            <span style=\"
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 11px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; \">Photos<br>
<span style=\"
font-weight: bold; \"><span style=\"
letter-spacing: 0px;\">".$sayi."</span></span></span>
        </div>
        <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 1.50%;
   width: 33.00%;\">
            <span style=\"
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 11px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; \">Followers<br>
 <span style=\"
font-weight: bold;\"><span style=\"
letter-spacing: 0px;\">".$takipci."</span></span></b></span>
        </div>
        <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: right;
   right: 0.50%;
   width: 31.00%;\">
          <span style=\"
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 11px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; \">Following<br><span style=\"
font-weight: bold;\"><span style=\"
letter-spacing: 0px;\">".$takipediyor."</span></span></span> 
        </div> 
    </div>
   </div>
   <br><br>

    "
;




foreach ($result->data as $fotos)
$instagramlink=$fotos->link;
    $instagramthumb=$fotos->images->thumbnail->url;
    $instagramlikes=$fotos->likes->count;


 echo "
<!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
        <span style=\"font-size: 12px; float:left; 
margin:5px 0 2px 10px;\">  
<a target=\"_blank\" class=\"group\" rel=\"group1\" href=\"".$instagramlink."\">
<img width=\"90\" src=\"".$instagramthumb."\"></a>
<span style=\"font-weight:bold; float:left;\"></span>
<span style=\"float:right;\"><span style=\"color:red; font-weight: bolder;\">❤ </span>".$instagramlikes."</span>
    </span>";

}


else {
echo "";
}
?>
```

Sorry for the answers. Here is the result of the var_dump.

```
    array(6) {
  [0]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#450 (15) {
    ["attribution"]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["tags"]=&gt;
    array(29) {
      [0]=&gt;
      string(11) "healthyfood"
      [1]=&gt;
      string(10) "gastronomi"
      [2]=&gt;
      string(8) "goodmood"
      [3]=&gt;
      string(6) "aegean"
      [4]=&gt;
      string(12) "egemutfağı"
      [5]=&gt;
      string(13) "istanbulnight"
      [6]=&gt;
      string(8) "goodfood"
      [7]=&gt;
      string(12) "istanbullife"
      [8]=&gt;
      string(9) "gastroart"
      [9]=&gt;
      string(5) "vegan"
      [10]=&gt;
      string(5) "gurme"
      [11]=&gt;
      string(18) "rokaperalezzetleri"
      [12]=&gt;
      string(9) "delicious"
      [13]=&gt;
      string(8) "rokapera"
      [14]=&gt;
      string(19) "sağlıklıyemekler"
      [15]=&gt;
      string(3) "eat"
      [16]=&gt;
      string(7) "cuisine"
      [17]=&gt;
      string(13) "rokaperabahce"
      [18]=&gt;
      string(8) "istanbul"
      [19]=&gt;
      string(15) "istanbuldayasam"
      [20]=&gt;
      string(8) "slowfood"
      [21]=&gt;
      string(8) "beyoğlu"
      [22]=&gt;
      string(9) "instafood"
      [23]=&gt;
      string(4) "food"
      [24]=&gt;
      string(6) "sunday"
      [25]=&gt;
      string(4) "meze"
      [26]=&gt;
      string(18) "istanbulrestaurant"
      [27]=&gt;
      string(5) "pazar"
      [28]=&gt;
      string(7) "fitfood"
    }
    ["type"]=&gt;
    string(5) "image"
    ["location"]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["comments"]=&gt;
    object(stdClass)#451 (2) {
      ["count"]=&gt;
      int(1)
      ["data"]=&gt;
      array(1) {
        [0]=&gt;
        object(stdClass)#452 (4) {
          ["created_time"]=&gt;
          string(10) "1451222250"
          ["text"]=&gt;
          string(37) "Bizim saksilarda da cok güzel oluyor"
          ["from"]=&gt;
          object(stdClass)#453 (4) {
            ["username"]=&gt;
            string(7) "rrahiya"
            ["profile_picture"]=&gt;
            string(107) "https://igcdn-photos-e-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpt1/t51.2885-19/11296890_1089406831069780_918421126_a.jpg"
            ["id"]=&gt;
            string(10) "1752184409"
            ["full_name"]=&gt;
            string(32) "Liberté, egalité, sensualité."
          }
          ["id"]=&gt;
          string(19) "1149257992582175831"
        }
      }
    }
    ["filter"]=&gt;
    string(6) "Normal"
    ["created_time"]=&gt;
    string(10) "1451222003"
    ["link"]=&gt;
    string(39) "https://www.instagram.com/p/_y-isiI5-I/"
    ["likes"]=&gt;
    object(stdClass)#454 (2) {
      ["count"]=&gt;
      int(147)
      ["data"]=&gt;
      array(4) {
        [0]=&gt;
        object(stdClass)#455 (4) {
          ["username"]=&gt;
          string(8) "cbnsibel"
          ["profile_picture"]=&gt;
          string(108) "https://igcdn-photos-f-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xta1/t51.2885-19/11379317_1589253931356213_2037606977_a.jpg"
          ["id"]=&gt;
          string(10) "1986547402"
          ["full_name"]=&gt;
          string(5) "sibel"
        }
        [1]=&gt;
        object(stdClass)#456 (4) {
          ["username"]=&gt;
          string(18) "artisanotelalacati"
          ["profile_picture"]=&gt;
          string(99) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-19/11193131_105208333143926_294676378_a.jpg"
          ["id"]=&gt;
          string(10) "1992036455"
          ["full_name"]=&gt;
          string(22) "Artisan Otel Alaçatı"
        }
        [2]=&gt;
        object(stdClass)#457 (4) {
          ["username"]=&gt;
          string(10) "inci.yaras"
          ["profile_picture"]=&gt;
          string(108) "https://igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xft1/t51.2885-19/11191206_1844971219060510_1434357002_a.jpg"
          ["id"]=&gt;
          string(10) "2108058746"
          ["full_name"]=&gt;
          string(13) "İNCİ YARAŞ"
        }
        [3]=&gt;
        object(stdClass)#458 (4) {
          ["username"]=&gt;
          string(17) "zerrinellialtoglu"
          ["profile_picture"]=&gt;
          string(115) "https://igcdn-photos-c-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xpa1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12277636_518301508335162_120675683_a.jpg"
          ["id"]=&gt;
          string(10) "2090528591"
          ["full_name"]=&gt;
          string(18) "Zerrinellialtioglu"
        }
      }
    }
    ["images"]=&gt;
    object(stdClass)#459 (3) {
      ["low_resolution"]=&gt;
      object(stdClass)#460 (3) {
        ["url"]=&gt;
        string(111) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xtp1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/12394199_518383638336848_87665054_n.jpg"
        ["width"]=&gt;
        int(320)
        ["height"]=&gt;
        int(320)
      }
      ["thumbnail"]=&gt;
      object(stdClass)#461 (3) {
        ["url"]=&gt;
        string(128) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xft1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.120.960.960/11261430_893913227383126_1405649502_n.jpg"
        ["width"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
      }
      ["standard_resolution"]=&gt;
      object(stdClass)#462 (3) {
        ["url"]=&gt;
        string(118) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xtp1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12394199_518383638336848_87665054_n.jpg"
        ["width"]=&gt;
        int(640)
        ["height"]=&gt;
        int(640)
      }
    }
    ["users_in_photo"]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["caption"]=&gt;
    object(stdClass)#463 (4) {
      ["created_time"]=&gt;
      string(10) "1451222003"
      ["text"]=&gt;
      string(355) "Keyifli Pazarlar 
#rokapera #egemutfağı #sağlıklıyemekler #vegan #aegean #cuisine #fitfood #meze #istanbul 
#rokaperabahce #rokaperalezzetleri #istanbul #istanbullife #istanbulrestaurant #istanbulnight #istanbuldayasam #beyoğlu #eat #delicious #gurme #gastronomi #gastroart #goodfood #goodmood #food  #healthyfood #instafood #slowfood #sunday #pazar"
      ["from"]=&gt;
      object(stdClass)#464 (4) {
        ["username"]=&gt;
        string(13) "rokaperabahce"
        ["profile_picture"]=&gt;
        string(108) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11909310_888061464574620_968185939_a.jpg"
        ["id"]=&gt;
        string(10) "1550397278"
        ["full_name"]=&gt;
        string(9) "Roka Pera"
      }
      ["id"]=&gt;
      string(19) "1149255927407550385"
    }
    ["user_has_liked"]=&gt;
    bool(false)
    ["id"]=&gt;
    string(30) "1149255918096195464_1550397278"
    ["user"]=&gt;
    object(stdClass)#465 (4) {
      ["username"]=&gt;
      string(13) "rokaperabahce"
      ["profile_picture"]=&gt;
      string(108) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/11909310_888061464574620_968185939_a.jpg"
      ["id"]=&gt;
      string(10) "1550397278"
      ["full_name"]=&gt;
      string(9) "Roka Pera"
    }
  }
  [1]=&gt;
  object(stdClass)#466 (15) {
    ["attribution"]=&gt;
    NULL
    ["tags"]=&gt;
    array(29) {
      [0]=&gt;
      string(11) "healthyfood"
      [1]=&gt;
      string(10) "gastronomi"
      [2]=&gt;
      string(8) "goodmood"
      [3]=&gt;
      string(6) "aegean"
      [4]=&gt;
      string(12) "egemutfağı"
      [5]=&gt;
      string(13) "istanbulnight"
      [6]=&gt;
      string(8) "goodfood"
      [7]=&gt;
      string(12) "istanbullife"
      [8]=&gt;
      string(9) "gastroart"
      [9]=&gt;
      string(5) "vegan"
      [10]=&gt;
      string(5) "gurme"
      [11]=&gt;
      string(18) "rokaperalezzetleri"
      [12]=&gt;
      string(9) "delicious"
      [13]=&gt;
      string(8) "rokapera"
      [14]=&gt;
      string(19) "sağlıklıyemekler"
      [15]=&gt;
      string(8) "saturday"
      [16]=&gt;
      string(7) "cuisine"
      [17]=&gt;
      string(13) "rokaperabahce"
      [18]=&gt;
      string(6) "flower"
      [19]=&gt;
      string(8) "istanbul"
      [20]=&gt;
      string(15) "istanbuldayasam"
      [21]=&gt;
      string(8) "slowfood"
      [22]=&gt;
      string(8) "beyoğlu"
      [23]=&gt;
      string(3) "eat"
      [24]=&gt;
      string(9) "instafood"
      [25]=&gt;
      string(4) "food"
      [26]=&gt;
      string(4) "meze"
      [27]=&gt;
      string(18) "istanbulrestaurant"
      [28]=&gt;
      string(7) "fitfood"
    }
    ["type"]=&gt;
    string(5) "image"
    ["location"]=&gt;
    object(stdClass)#467 (4) {
      ["latitude"]=&gt;
      float(41.029172249)
      ["name"]=&gt;
      string(18) "Roka Pera Istanbul"
      ["longitude"]=&gt;
      float(28.97304208)
      ["id"]=&gt;
      int(226441757)
    }
    ["comments"]=&gt;
    object(stdClass)#468 (2) {
      ["count"]=&gt;
      int(0)
      ["data"]=&gt;
      array(0) {
      }
    }
    ["filter"]=&gt;
    string(6) "Normal"
    ["created_time"]=&gt;
    string(10) "1451143170"
    ["link"]=&gt;
    string(39) "https://www.instagram.com/p/_woLm7o571/"
    ["likes"]=&gt;
    object(stdClass)#469 (2) {
      ["count"]=&gt;
      int(124)
      ["data"]=&gt;
      array(4) {
        [0]=&gt;
        object(stdClass)#470 (4) {
          ["username"]=&gt;
          string(10) "inci.yaras"
          ["profile_picture"]=&gt;
          string(108) "https://igcdn-photos-g-a.akamaihd.net/hphotos-ak-xft1/t51.2885-19/11191206_1844971219060510_1434357002_a.jpg"
          ["id"]=&gt;
          string(10) "2108058746"
          ["full_name"]=&gt;
          string(13) "İNCİ YARAŞ"
        }
        [1]=&gt;
        object(stdClass)#471 (4) {
          ["username"]=&gt;
          string(8) "nerminhm"
          ["profile_picture"]=&gt;
          string(99) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xfa1/t51.2885-19/11375775_368087600058975_581007122_a.jpg"
          ["id"]=&gt;
          string(10) "2125331353"
          ["full_name"]=&gt;
          string(22) "Nermin Hocaoğlu Mutlu"
        }
        [2]=&gt;
        object(stdClass)#472 (4) {
          ["username"]=&gt;
          string(12) "betulozkayaa"
          ["profile_picture"]=&gt;
          string(110) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xpt1/t51.2885-19/s150x150/12353384_1688926777992013_1604858269_a.jpg"
          ["id"]=&gt;
          string(10) "2188974742"
          ["full_name"]=&gt;
          string(14) "Betül Özkaya"
        }
        [3]=&gt;
        object(stdClass)#473 (4) {
          ["username"]=&gt;
          string(10) "comoburger"
          ["profile_picture"]=&gt;
          string(100) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xaf1/t51.2885-19/11378524_1409822219347310_349229698_a.jpg"
          ["id"]=&gt;
          string(10) "2130593263"
          ["full_name"]=&gt;
          string(17) "Hamburger Gourmet"
        }
      }
    }
    ["images"]=&gt;
    object(stdClass)#474 (3) {
      ["low_resolution"]=&gt;
      object(stdClass)#498 (3) {
        ["url"]=&gt;
        string(113) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xft1/t51.2885-15/s320x320/e35/12362432_600511983432932_1619827376_n.jpg"
        ["width"]=&gt;
        int(320)
        ["height"]=&gt;
        int(320)
      }
      ["thumbnail"]=&gt;
      object(stdClass)#497 (3) {
        ["url"]=&gt;
        string(131) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xtp1/t51.2885-15/s150x150/e35/c0.135.1080.1080/12345975_1506337882995996_2045435867_n.jpg"
        ["width"]=&gt;
        int(150)
        ["height"]=&gt;
        int(150)
      }
      ["standard_resolution"]=&gt;
      object(stdClass)#496 (3) {
        ["url"]=&gt;
        string(120) "https://scontent.cdninstagram.com/hphotos-xft1/t51.2885-15/s640x640/sh0.08/e35/12362432_600511983432932_1619827376_n.jpg"
        ["width"]=&gt;
        int(640)
        ["height"]=&gt;
        int(640)
      }
    }
    ["users_in_photo"]=&gt;
    array(0) {
    }
    ["caption"]=&gt;
    object(stdClass)#495 (4) {
      ["created_time"]=&gt;
      string(10) "1451143170"
      ["text"]=&gt;
      string(375) "Cumartesi Çiçekleri
```

Comment: where does `$result->data` come from?

Comment: What I mean is can you show us what `$result->data` contains?

Comment: did you var_dump your `$result->data` ?

Comment: I see you close the foreach but not open it with { ? Or am I crazy?

Comment: lol, that's a problem as well, I only looked to make sure it was closed

Comment: I didn't notice i didn't open it properly since it has been working. I've opened it properly now but the loop still shows only one result. @ChrisTrudeau

Comment: What did you get for a result with the var_dump of $result->data like @ChrisTrudeau and Antoine Pointeau suggested?

Comment: var_dump($result->data); and add the output of that to your original question. Don't post it as an answer

Comment: DO NOT post additional information as answers.  EDIT your question and provide the information!

Comment: I'm sorry, I just did that. @cale_b

Comment: I've updated the post with the var_dump result. @ChrisTrudeau

Comment: The data you posted gets cut off soon after the first object out of six, not sure if that's a stackoverflow length limit or if it's actually cut off in the data you're using in your code.

Comment: Can you check the code I posted below as an answer? (Sorry about that again) It used to work when it was coded that way. Also, another question, do you think I can take the loop out of the first if & else statement and define another if & else and put it inside that one? @ChrisTrudeau

Comment: See my answer, I think I may have solved it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While we spotted that you didn't have an opening `{` to your foreach loop, you also didn't have an ending `}` for your if statement. Try changing that code to:

```
if ( $instagramid ) 
{
    echo "


<br><br>
<span style=\"float:left; -webkit-border-radius: 3px;
border-radius: 3px;
font-size: 14px;
float: left;
line-height: 32px;
margin-right: 5px;
margin-top:12px;
padding: 0px 3px 0px 5px;
\">
<a target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://instagram.com/".$username."\"><img width=\"80\" border=\"1px\" src=\"".$profilepic."\"></a></span>
<br>
<div style=\"margin-left: 50px;\">
     <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 0.00%;
   width: 75.00%;
   background-color: #f4f4f4\">
       <span style=\"
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 12px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; \"><a style=\"color: #3f729b; font-weight: bold; \" target=\"_blank\" href=\"http://instagram.com/".$username."\">".$username."</a> @ instagram</span>
    </div>
    <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 0.00%;
   width: 82.00%;\">
        <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 0.50%;
   width: 33.00%;\">
            <span style=\"
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 11px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; \">Photos<br>
<span style=\"
font-weight: bold; \"><span style=\"
letter-spacing: 0px;\">".$sayi."</span></span></span>
        </div>
        <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: left;
   left: 1.50%;
   width: 33.00%;\">
            <span style=\"
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 11px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; \">Followers<br>
 <span style=\"
font-weight: bold;\"><span style=\"
letter-spacing: 0px;\">".$takipci."</span></span></b></span>
        </div>
        <div style=\"position: relative;
   float: right;
   right: 0.50%;
   width: 31.00%;\">
          <span style=\"
font-weight: lighter;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 11px; letter-spacing: 0px; padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px; \">Following<br><span style=\"
font-weight: bold;\"><span style=\"
letter-spacing: 0px;\">".$takipediyor."</span></span></span> 
        </div> 
    </div>
   </div>
   <br><br>

    "
;




    foreach ($result->data as $fotos)
    {
        $instagramlink=$fotos->link;
        $instagramthumb=$fotos->images->thumbnail->url;
        $instagramlikes=$fotos->likes->count;


         echo "
<!-- Renders images. @Options (thumbnail,low_resoulution, high_resolution) -->
        <span style=\"font-size: 12px; float:left; 
margin:5px 0 2px 10px;\">  
<a target=\"_blank\" class=\"group\" rel=\"group1\" href=\"".$instagramlink."\">
<img width=\"90\" src=\"".$instagramthumb."\"></a>
<span style=\"font-weight:bold; float:left;\"></span>
<span style=\"float:right;\"><span style=\"color:red; font-weight: bolder;\">❤ </span>".$instagramlikes."</span>
    </span>";

    }
}
else 
{
    echo "";
}
```

These types of mistakes are very easy to spot if you use clean and consistent formatting throughout your code! Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: That worked like a charm!!! Thank you very, very much! Your help is much appreciated and sorry again for posting information as an answer.

Comment: No worries, it's just to keep the site organized and useful, good luck with your project